# Incluir el valor de una variable definida con R en código JS javascript

Tags: javascript, r

¿Cómo podría incluir el valor de una variable definida con R en un script JS también definido en R?

Debería ser algo así:

```
maxvaluex <- 150
jsCodeEx <- JS("function() {
 this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.dataMin, maxvaluex);
 }")
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que se está empleado el paquete `library(htmlwidgets)`. En tal sentido, se puede usar la función `paste0`

```
library(htmlwidgets)

maxvaluex <- 150
js_function<-paste0("function() {this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.dataMin, ", maxvaluex, ");}")
js_function
# "function() {this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.dataMin, 150);}"
```

Dado que hay que correr el código desde el servidor y la expresión no puede ser verificada porque depende de otras variables y/o atributos `this.xAxis[0].setExtremes...` voy a emplear otro paquete para demostrar como se insertan no sólo variables, sino vectores de `R` en `javascript`

```
# install.packages("js")
library(js)

vector <- paste(1:10, collapse = ",") # se genera un vector de 1 al 10
js_eval( paste0("[", vector, "].map(x => x**2)") ) # cuadrado del 1 al 10
# "1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100"
```

Nótese que en este caso, el arreglo o vector puede ser logrado directamente por el interprete de `R` usando `arrow functions` de `javascript`

```
js_eval("[...Array(10).keys()].map(x => (x+1)**2)") # se indexa desde 0 por eso x+1
# "1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100"
```

Aquí el ejemplo en `javascript` para verificar lo expuesto previamente

```js
let potencias = [...Array(10).keys()].map(x => (x+1)**2)
console.log(potencias)
```